# SwiftUI: The problem is saving data in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I want to save the data in the database `profileDB.lvl` that is transferred from another property `self.lvl`

At the beginning of ContentView I prescribed:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
```

And

```
@State public var lvl = 0
let profileDB = ProfileUser(context: self.managedObjectContext)
```

Then, in the button below, I prescribed the logic of saving:

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut){

        profileDB.lvl = Int16(self.lvl)

        do{
            if progress < 300{
                progress += 75
            } else if progress == 300{
                progress = 50
                self.lvl += 1
            }
            
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
},
       label: {
    Text("Perform")
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .font(.system(size: 18, design: .default))
})
```

And it turns out that the data is changed in self.lvl, but not assigned to profileDB.lvl 
Am I having trouble with the correct implementation, what can help solve the problem?

Comment: First you assign profileDB.lvl the value of self.lvl and _after_ that you change the value of self.lvl and since Int is a value type profileDB.lvl is not updated. So do it in the opposite order, update self.lvl and then update profileDB.

Comment: if `let profileDB =...` is a property on your view, this will be creating a new entry in the context every time this view is initialised (which could be a lot!). You should be fetching or creating this object elsewhere and having it as an observed object property of the view.

Comment: @jrturton We can ask you to demonstrate so that it is more understandable. And this will help to solve the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

What @jrturton is saying is twofold:

You are assigning the value of the `@State var lvl` to the managed object `profileDB.lvl` BEFORE you update `@State var lvl`. You are not binding `@State var lvl` to `profileDB.lvl` (nor would you want to) so it doesn't update when `@State var lvl` does. So, change the order:

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut){

        do{
            if progress < 300{
                progress += 75
            } else if progress == 300{
                progress = 50
                self.lvl += 1
            }
            profileDB.lvl = Int16(self.lvl)


            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
},
       label: {
    Text("Perform")
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .font(.system(size: 18, design: .default))
})
```

However, you have another issue. Every time this view appears, you are creating a new managed object and giving it a value. That may be what you intend. Generally, you would pass in the one object that is keeping this particular user's profile, and would update that. Not create a new user with no other info except the updated level.

Comment: I tried swapping the code, but it didn't help to assign data to `profileDB.lvl`, it remains still 0.

Comment: That doesn't mean it is not working. You really need a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, review the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The button is conditional. You may not be satisfying the condition. Writing an MRE will allow you to test whether your Core Data code it correct. Also, once you create and add this managed object, how are you viewing it? This is answered by an MRE.